# Multi Threading Safe SQLite

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, sqlite

I have a class that is in `C#` on Winforms and it is not thread safe, but I want it to be. Instead `SQLite` is constantly erroring saying that the db is locked.. the db is locked..

However I already planned for this: there is meant to be one Queue which is FIFO (which is fine) *BUT* this worker thread (non gui) is competing against the GUI because there are some gui events that need to go to the db too, and they are banging into each other.. causing items to fail which then spirals out of control.

All I really want is to be able to get a SQLite connection from whatever thread I need to and expect it to stay up. I do this sort of thing in MySQL all the time and it has never burped once in nearly 15 years..

**So, My Question is**

is there a) a bullet proof way to have a SQLite query that simply waits and is there a way to manually lock transactions (maybe in it's own thread?) or b) is there an easy way to force SQLite to not be so fussy. There is a lot of SQL going on and it's only when I scaled up the Winforms Application that these issues became apparent. I cannot afford to do a total rewrite.

Incidentally I used this DefaultTimeout to try to achieve some gains but this also simply lowers the issue threshold and it feels sub optimal

```
SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DefaultTimeout = 200;
builder.DataSource = "some.sqlite";
builder.Version = 3;
conn = new SQLiteConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
```

Comment: There is no reason to keep the connection open.  Open it, get your data, close it.

Comment: Make sure you dispose of connections and commands as soon as you're done with them. Wrap them in `using` statements.

Comment: @LarsTech I do do this but it makes no difference, because I am Queueing Inserts and selecting at the same time from 2 threads @Blorgbeard yes I will have a look at `using`

Comment: "there is meant to be one Queue which is FIFO (which is fine) BUT this worker thread (non gui) is competing against the GUI because there are some gui events that need to go to the db too" -- what's the point of the "one" queue if the GUI thread is **also** going direct to the database? It should be enqueuing queries and waiting for results.

Comment: @Blorgbeard this is clearly something we will differ on, there is no implicit reason why even a dozen concurrent connections cannot be served by a single database, it is a primary structure, in fact: in first principles it only differs from a file system in that it allows concurrent transactions. I do not even want a database if it isn't able to be a database.. this bizarre declaration that SQLite "should not be threaded" "we do it as a concession" is appalling logic. It should just call itself FLATFILElite

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'force SQLite to not be so fussy' - it is telling you that if you do what you're trying to do bad things will happen - e.g a crash, or database corruption, or worse.

I suggest you look into wrapping access to SQLite in a thread of its own, which you then treat as a server with a proper thread-blockable interface. Try to avoid using shared resources. Being on its own thread should make the db happy, and your other code can block or poll as required until access is possible. As a benefit you will gain a bit more multicore flexibility.

If you can't do that, you could try using 'monitors', sometimes known as 'synchronised' calls. however be very aware that this is a path paved with pitfalls which are only easy to spot after the event.

HTH

Comment: thanks, on a different note, it may be I need it compiled to be thread safe: how do I check if my version of the SQLite DLL is http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html sqlite3_threadsafe() do you know?